# How to write the following function so that gradient can be found before putting the variable values

Tags: matlab, derivative

```
function [y] = sumsqu(xx)

d = length(xx);
sum = 0;
for ii = 1:d
    xi = xx(ii);
    sum = sum + ii*xi^2;
end

y = sum;

end
```

Above is the code for `d` variables. Whenever I call the function I get the sum as expected. Now I want to find the numerical gradient of the function. But since the function is returning a scalar value, `gradient` returns 0 obviously. What can I do so that `gradient` first evaluates in its variable form then return an array corresponding to `[x1 x2 x3....xd]`?

[image: Sample procedure]

As you can see in the picture, I want it in that order. And I also want `d` as a variable so that code can be generic. Hope you understood my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your function does exactly this:

```
y = sum(xx.^2 .* (1:numel(xx)));
```

The derivatives then are:

```
y = 2*xx .* (1:numel(xx));
```

(according to the hand-written equations).

---

You should avoid using `sum` as a variable name, you can see above that it is an important function, if you assign a value to `sum`, you hide the function and can no longer use it.

Comment: your answer is better

Answer (score 1):

For your specific function, you can calculate the gradient analytically like:

g = 2*(1:length(xx)).*xx;

You can also replace the call for length(xx) by d if it is given.

Comment: It does happen at times that someone else posts an answer while you’re typing up yours. It is not very common in the MATLAB tag, though, there’s not that many people answering here. :)